# Create Json Data after Reading text file

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am working on  online examination system , the teacher should be able to import questions from text file  , which has questions like this

```
what is the capital of USA?
NewYork
*Washington
Texas

what is the Capital of UAE?
DUBAI
*ABU Dhabi
Alriadh
```

I want to go through this file line by line and if the line contains question's Mark (?) so I can decide it is question part and the lines till find the next question are the answers to this question  and the option that has a star beside it can be considered as the right answer
at the end of this loop, I need to have JSON data like this

```
{"questions": {"id": "1596805341211", "type": "Multiple Choice Single Answer", "question": "what is the capital of USA? ",   "answer_options": {"1596805341213": {"marks": null, "value": "NewYork"}, "1596805363748": {"marks": null, "value": "Washington"}, "1596805372883": {"marks": "100", "value": "Texas", "selected": "Selected"}}},{"id": "1596805341212", "type": "Multiple Choice Single Answer", "question": "what is the Capital of UAE?",   "answer_options": {"1596805341213": {"marks": null, "value": "DUBAI"}, "1596805363748": {"marks": null, "value": "ABU Dhabi"}, "1596805372883": {"marks": "100", "value": "Alriadh", "selected": "Selected"}}}}
```

I tried with this code but I stuck and I don't know how to continue

```
$handle = fopen("test.txt", "r");
        if ($handle) {
            $qusetions[][]=array() ;
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
                if( Str::contains($line, '?')==1)
                {  array_push($qusetions,$line);
                }
                else{
                  
                }


            }

            fclose($handle);
        } else {

            echo "Can not open";


        }
```

Comment: Where do the IDs come from? How do I know which answer is correct? I don't see these in the text file.

Comment: thank you for your reply , the id is generated ,in php file ,

Comment: for the right answer yes it is my fault that I forget to explain that id the option has star   beside the answer  so I will consider it as right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it can solve your problem.

```
$questions = [];
$i = 0;
$questionsFile = fopen(base_path('/public/questions.txt'), 'r');
while ($line = fgets($questionsFile)) {
    if ($line === "\n") {
        $i++;
        continue;
    }
    if (!isset($questions['questions'][$i])){
        $questions['questions'][$i] = [
            'id' => rand(1596805341210, 9999999999999),
            'type' => 'Multiple Choice Single Answer',
            'question' => '',
            'answer_options' => []
        ];
    }

    if (preg_match("/(.)+\?/", $line)) {
        $questions['questions'][$i]['question'] = $line;
    } else {
        $answer = [
            'id' => rand(1596805341210, 9999999999999),
            'marks' => null,
            'value' => $line,
            'selected' => false,
        ];
        if (preg_match("/(\*)(.)+/", $line)) {
            $answer['marks'] = 100;
            $answer['selected'] = true;
        }
        $questions['questions'][$i]['answer_options'][] = $answer;
    }
}
fclose($questionsFile);
return $questions;
```